# Switch animation through 'If Statement' in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I have some code in jQuery in which I want to make a switch animate on or off by clicking on a div. Here is the code. When I test it, it doesn't work. However if I remove `toggle = true` on line 7, it just works one way and I can't turn it back off.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#switch").click(function () {
        var toggle = false;
        if (toggle == false) {
            $("#circle").css("left", "27px");
            $("#white_rect").attr("src", "green_rect.png");
            toggle = true;
        }
        if (toggle == true) {
            $("#circle").css("left", "1px");
            $("#white_rect").attr("src", "white_rect.png");
            toggle = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML too? or fiddle link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the `toggle` variable outside of the click handler... else in every click call the variable will get reinitialized so the value of the variable will always be false.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //declare it here
    var toggle = false;
    $("#switch").click(function () {
        if (toggle == false) {
            $("#circle").css("left", "27px");
            $("#white_rect").attr("src", "green_rect.png");
            toggle = true;
        //also don't use a separate if block here as it will be affected by the execution of the above if block
        } else {
            $("#circle").css("left", "1px");
            $("#white_rect").attr("src", "white_rect.png");
            toggle = false;
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //declare it here
    var toggle = false;
    $("#switch").click(function () {
        if (toggle) {
            $("#circle").css("left", "1px");
            $("#white_rect").attr("src", "white_rect.png");
        } else {
            $("#circle").css("left", "27px");
            $("#white_rect").attr("src", "green_rect.png");
        }
        toggle = !toggle;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to strictly divide appearance and logic. So use `.classes` and backgounded `<div>`s instead of `<img>`. Then you won't need any state variables and code shall be more simple.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="switch off"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
    width:100%; height:100px; padding:40px; text-align:center;
}
.container .switch {
    width:94px; height: 27px; display:inline-block; background-color:pink; cursor:pointer;
}
.container .switch.on {
    background: url('http://squad.pw/tmp/img/01-on.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
.container .switch.off {
    background: url('http://squad.pw/tmp/img/01-off.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$('.switch').click(function() {

    // Do visual logic
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $(this).toggleClass('off');

    // Do business logic
    window.toggle = !window.toggle;
});
```

Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oxfn/ntPg7/2/)